# Transforming columns into numerical values when copying

Tags: python, pandas, data-conversion, columnsorting

I have a data frame which I read in via

`data = pd.read_csv("animals_clean.csv")`

It contains a column which has over 67000 values and the same 80+ values are repeated throughout.
such as:

```
   Ailurus
   Harpia
   Alligator
   Branta
   Araucaria
   Branta
   Alligator
```

I would like to create a column next to it which takes each individual type and assigns it a numerical value.
such as

```
1
2
3
4
5
4
3
```

currently my only option is to do it manually via

```
data['animal'].replace(['harpia'], ['2'],inplace=True)
```

however this would not be viable as this would take time

Comment: Why does  alligator have two different numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
df['num_A']=df.A.astype('category').cat.codes
```

Or

```
df['num_A']=df.A.factorize()[0]
```

Or

```
df.groupby('A').ngroup()
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended using the second one with a slight adjustment  ```data['nom_tax] = data['App.'].factorize(str)[0]```